# How do I test a Bambora iframe's event listeners in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

so I am using Bambora which is loaded as a `useRef` hook into React and using Jest & React Testing Library to test the component. After the component is loaded, `useEffect` runs and mounts Bambora's iframe into the DOM input fields & adds event listeners for error validations.

```
  const addListeners = () => {
    customCheckout.current.on('error', (event) => {
      console.log('event', event);
      event.field === config.ccNumber.name && setCcError(event.message);
      event.field === config.ccCvv.name && setCvvError(event.message);
      event.field === config.ccExpiry.name && setExpiryError(event.message);
    });

    customCheckout.current.on('complete', (event) => {
      event.field === config.ccNumber.name && setCcError('');
      event.field === config.ccCvv.name && setCvvError('');
      event.field === config.ccExpiry.name && setExpiryError('');
    });
  };
```

How do I test event listeners in Jest / React Testing Library as the test runner doesn't seem to see the iframe fields mounted properly (useEffect's functions don't seem to be invoked)?

I have tried mocking the `useRef` and directly dispatching the event but it still doesn't find the event message to be set:

```
it('invoke ccError event listener', async (done) => {
    const mRef = {
      current: {
        on: (arg1, arg2) => {
          if (arg1 === 'error') {
            let e = { field: 'card-number', message: 'card number error' };
            arg2(e);
          }
        },
      },
    };

    useRef.mockReturnValueOnce(mRef);
    const mEvent = new Event('error', {
      field: 'card-number',
      message: 'card number error',
    });

const input = await screen.findByText('card number error');
expect(input).toBeTruthy;
```